# SQL python concatenation error

Tags: python, sql

In order to create a table in PostGIS, I am trying to run a python script using string chains and variables, the syntax of the SQL code where I have issues is:

```
table_sql =  ('CREATE TABLE %s (' % name_table
              'gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(%s)' % name_seq
              ',point_x numeric'
              ',point_y numeric'
              ',grid_code double precision'
              ',geom geometry(Point, %d)' % srd_id
              ',CONSTRAINT %s PRIMARY KEY(gid))' % name_pkey)
print table_sql
```

And when I execute that code (I am using MS-DOS console), it says:

```
File "csv2postgis.py", line 63
'gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(%s)' % name_seq
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using the psycopg2 module. Before I tried using triple quotes (""") as the https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingDbApiWithPostgres suggest when talking about DB-API 2.0, but I was not able to append those variables to the main string chain, and this is the reason why now I am trying to make it work using simple quotes.

Comment: You are not using parameters here at all. Please read the [DBAPI Guide for Postgresql](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingDbApiWithPostgres).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Only `srd_id` can be used as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I succeeded in creating the SQL string as a python variable:

`table_sql = """CREATE TABLE %s (gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('%s'),point_x numeric,point_y numeric,value double precision,name varchar(50),geom geometry(Point, %%s),CONSTRAINT %s PRIMARY KEY(gid))""" % (name_table, name_seq, name_pkey)`

Comment: Right, so my second example was missing the opening `(` after the table name; that's a typo on my part; corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic string concatenation (`'foo' 'bar'`) only works if there is nothing but whitespace between the strings.

In your case, you have several string interpolations in the middle. Move those all to the end, in a tuple

```
table_sql =  ('CREATE TABLE %s ('
              'gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(%s)'
              ',point_x numeric'
              ',point_y numeric'
              ',grid_code double precision'
              ',geom geometry(Point, %d)'
              ',CONSTRAINT %s PRIMARY KEY(gid))' % (
                  name_table, name_seq, srd_id, name_pkey)
              )
```

For *values*, you'd be better of using [SQL parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). For the names (`name_table`, `name_seq`, and `name_pkey`), if these are accepted from user input, **validate these** against known object names.

`srd_id` should be given as a SQL parameter instead; replace the `%d` with `%%s` (to escape the placeholder), then pass the value in to `cur.execute()`:

```
table_sql = '''\
    CREATE TABLE %s (
        gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(%s)
       ,point_x numeric
       ,point_y numeric
       ,grid_code double precision
       ,geom geometry(Point, %%s)
       ,CONSTRAINT %s PRIMARY KEY(gid))
''' % (name_table, name_seq, name_pkey)
cur.execute(table_sql, (srd_id,))
```

Now the database adapter will take care of the correct escaping of the value.